# Javascript: element onchange event async/await callback

Tags: javascript

I hope this question is not duplicated.
I have two HTML elements, one which when it's changed must populate the value of another via an async method named `foo()`.

The following code **works**:

```
<input type="text" id="elem">
<input type="file" onchange="
    (async ()=>{
       document.getElementById('elem').value = await foo(this);
    })()
">
```

The following one **doesn't** (no exception is thrown in console, and `#elem` is not updated):

```
<input type="text" id="elem">
<input type="file" onchange="
   async ()=>{
      document.getElementById('elem').value = await foo(this);
   }
">
```

Why the first example works and the second doesn't?

Comment: The first snippet executes the method via the IIFE.  The second one does not.

Comment: When you assign "onchange" in the attribute of the tag, as you're doing, you have to include the entire script, including the "()" to execute a function. If you were assigning it in a script, like "myinput.onchange = " and not in the tag, then you would just use the function name or the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(function() {...})()` This invokes the function.
it's like invoking a named function `someFunction()`

in your second example you're just creating a function without invoking it. it returns the function itself.

1. invoking:

```
onchange='someFn()'; // calls function
```

2. without invoking

```
onchange='someFn'; // returns function.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example is what is known as a [self invoking function](https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/). This is why is is wrapped in () and is followed by () to call the function immediately.

The second answer isn't working because you are not actually calling it. Simply add "const myFunc = async () => {}" and call "myFunc" on the button click.