# Fetch API returning previous data

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I'm trying to write a fetch to get data from an API. The data within the network tab shows the correct data that I want to update to my html, but the data that ends up there is always the previously returned data currently.

For example, I load the page with quantity selected = 1, the price per item returns properly as 2.25, when I switch to 6, the expected price per item returned is 2.14 (discount taken care of in another script) this is the price shown in the network tab. Unfortunately this isn't the price that gets updated into my html span. it will still show the 2.25 until I make another selection, then it will update to the  2.14. This is the problem, my html always seems to be loading the previously calls result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
  var span = document.getElementById("price-span");  
  
  //Call to cart API
  async function start() {
  const headers = new Headers(); 
  headers.append('pragma', 'no-cache'); 
  headers.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');
  await fetch('/cart.js', {
    method: 'GET' , headers: headers                      
  })
    .then(promise => promise.json())
    .then(data => render(data))
  }
  
  //Helper Functions  
  async function render(data) {
    span.textContent = "$" + insertDecimal(data.items[0].discounted_price) + " CAD";
    console.log(data.items[0].discounted_price)
  }
  
  function insertDecimal(num) {
   return Number((num / 100).toFixed(2));
  }

</script>
```

**Note: The total price functions properly and was written previously by someone else.**

[image: picture for ref]

[image: how the start is called]

Comment: `.then(data => render(data))` can be written as `.then(render)` but that won't solve your issue. You need to `await start()` wherever you call it. You didn't show us that code either.

Comment: my guess is `span` ain't the element you think it is.

Comment: @epascarello The span is changing but only on my the second click, its targeting right but passing the previous fetch data every time if that makes sense

Comment: How is `start` called? Is this your actual code?

Comment: Somewhere you're missing an `async => await` combo, or so it seems. I'm assuming start is called in an onclick or onchange, which should be `await`ed. Also, `pictures of code < actual code`

Comment: @epascarello added a picture of the start call, its in the onchange="start()" of the select

Comment: @RichardBarker yeah its in the select

Comment: You realize that onchange on select can fire multiple times. Are you sure you are getting the calls in the correct order back?

Comment: So... `onchange="async event => await start()"` should do it. If not, look into how Promises resolve. That's where your issue is.

Comment: @epascarello as far as I can tell, I want the user to be able to edit the quantity and the price will reflect instantly with the discount. It seems to be working perfect except for showing the previous calls data

Comment: `async function start() { console.log('start', Date.now());` do you see start being triggered more than once?

Comment: @RichardBarker onchange="async event => await start()" seemed to not work, broke the functionality. Doesn't do anything now

Comment: @epascarello added that code and it is only triggering once

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196668/javascript-element-onchange-event-async-await-callback

Comment: The correct code should be then according to that question's answer `onchange="(async event => {await start();})()"`

Comment: @RichardBarker not going to make any difference.

Comment: @RichardBarker that function call is working but the same problem is persisting

Comment: I would add headers to make sure the request is not cached.
`const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('pragma', 'no-cache');
headers.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');const response = await fetch('/cart.js', {
      method: 'GET' , headers: headers                  
    })`

Comment: @epascarello Added that code and the problem still persists unfortunately

Comment: If it helps any, I can see the call its making in the network tab on every change and its returning the proper data in there. Its just not using that data to update the span for some reason

Comment: So does `console.log(data.items[0].discounted_price)` log the correct value?

Comment: @epascarello that logs the incorrect old data value as well

Comment: Well then I would say you have a caching issue with the call. It really is impossible for me to guess why.

Comment: It's not caching. The browser doesn't typically cache that way from my experience. The issue lies somewhere in how and when your fetch promise resolves. It seems as if the fetch resolves after updating the span. I'd like to point out that `const response` isn't needed, and more over isn't actually the response - it's a promise. It's possible that, combined with the then using the same variable name, is playing some role in your issue as well

Comment: @RichardBarker I think you're right in that its how my promise resolves, I can see the cart data coming through the network after the page is built.

Comment: Still looking for suggestions if anyone can help :)

Comment: Maybe try removing the wrapper function `start` and call the `fetch` directly in the onchange, using the same syntax as in that question I linked above. Doubt it will help but it'll work to eliminate possible breaking points. Also, as I noted above, don't assign the promise returned by `fetch.then.then` to a variable, especially an incorrectly named one.

Comment: I took the const out of there like suggested! And am attempting to call the function in the onchange but can't get it to work, what exactly would that look like?

Comment: most likely, you are fetching the cart before the cart has been updated. The code you provided is not useful in debugging this issue.

Comment: @KevinB wouldn't I see this in the Network data that comes back though? Its showing the correct data.

Comment: @cd131313 see what, exactly?

Comment: If you can prove the fetch is returning what you expect it to, and the wrong value is written to your page, that should be *very* easy to debug.

Comment: @KevinB when I open the dev tools and go to the Network tab after switching the quantity select I can see my data coming back as what I am expecting. But the span that is supposed to be updated with this data always seems one click behind

Comment: In that case, you can remove the fetch from the equation entirely. Just hardcode it and write the value to the page. Does it work as expected? I don't understand where the breakdown in debugging this is if you know the fetch is returning the right value. At that point, it's not a fetch problem at all.

Comment: @KevinB oh, I thought the whole time that the data was coming from my fetch but you're right. I removed it and the returned cart is still there.

Comment: My problem with your explanation is this: you say, `start` is called when a selectbox changes. but start does *nothing* to change the quantities in your cart, it just fetches a result. so I have no idea how any of this would result in a quantity or price change.

Comment: @kevinb the fetch returns, but the span's new value isn't displayed in the DOM until the next fetch call occurs. `start` is just a wrapper around the promise. Also, @cd131313, `then(promise => promise.json())` in this case, `promise` is actually the response. It was the other place that it wasn't.

Comment: @KevinB yeah its all confusing to me to, trying to work on top of something that an agency built. The code to change the cart quantity and total price is all built in and working. I'm just attempting to update the product price line to show the price after a discount that gets applied elsewhere.

Comment: I see. i think you might be approaching this from the wrong direction then

Comment: What causes the discount to be applied?

Comment: there is an app called Script Editor in shopify that uses Ruby to apply the discount, its based on a tag existing on the product

Comment: effectively, whenever that occurs, you'd need to run your start method to have it request the cart and update the page once it's done